# Android: данные из AsyncTask 2

Tags: android, java

Опять обращаюсь с проблемой, когда из образа класса беру значение переменной, в этом классе нужное мне значение,а в активити куда я его передаю - null (или стандартное значение). Пробовал юзать интерфейс - не помогло. Класс:

```
   public class ShowBar extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long>
{
   ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
   public String info = "que-";
   private  boolean today = true;
   private Context  context_dialog;

   public ShowBar(Context context, boolean day)
   {
      context_dialog = context;

      today = day;
   }

   @Override
   protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
       super.onProgressUpdate(values);    //To change body of overridden methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
   }

   @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(Long aLong) {
       super.onPostExecute(aLong);
       mProgressDialog.dismiss();
       FootballView foot = new FootballView();
       foot.OnComplete(this.info);
       //foot.info = this.info; // тоже null

   }

   @Override
   protected void onPreExecute() {
       mProgressDialog =
               ProgressDialog.show
                       (context_dialog
                               , "Загрузка"
                               , "Подождите, идёт загрузка", true);

       mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
       mProgressDialog.show();
   }

   @Override
   protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
       long result = 0;
       Elements links;

       final String URL = "http://ya.ru";

       if (today)
           {

               Document doc = null;
               try {
                   doc = Jsoup.connect(URL).get();
                   links = doc.select("table[class=translation]");
                   info =  links.outerHtml();

               }catch (Exception e){

               }
           }

       return result;

   }

}
```

Активити:

```
    public class FootballView extends ListActivity implements View.OnClickListener, OnCompleteListener {
    ...
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
           button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.TodayYesterday);
           button1.setOnClickListener(this);
           textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mainView1);

              bar = new ShowBar(this,true);

              bar.execute();

    }

@Override
    public void OnComplete(String infos) {

        info = infos;

    }
```

Интерфейс:

```
public interface OnCompleteListener {
    void OnComplete(String infos);
}
```

Думаю с интерфейсом творю что-то не то =(

Comment: а зачем вот эта строка? 

    FootballView foot = new FootballView();

используйте передаваемый параметр

То есть пусть у вас будет конструктор 

    public ShowBar(Context context, OnCompleteListener listener, boolean day) { 
    this.listener = listener
    ...
    }

затем уже вызывайте

    listener.onComplete(this.info)

Answer (score 1):

Думаю так будет лучше.

```
@Override
       protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
           //...
           return nill;
       }
```

//

```
 final String URL = "http://ya.ru";
    bar.execute(URL);
```